# Drawable is in drawable-mdpi folder but tree in Android project is empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I just pasted couple of files in drawable-mdpi folder and am able to see them physically in this folder. But I don't see them in my Android project folder. How to update project and why I don't see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that Android Studio has not refreshed its directories and, as such, has not added the new resources to the project tree. Try right clicking on the resources directory ("res") and selecting "Synchronize" from the menu option. This should refresh the tree and then the images you added should show up. You can also try cleaning and rebuilding the project ("Build" --> "Rebuild Project" and "Build" --> "Clean Project").

Comment: Don't forget to Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: I put everything in folder, like drawable-mdpi\category\1.png. Seems that subfolders are not supported. I did not know that.